# How to undo an action in gmsh

Tags: mesh, undo

I just connected two points with a straight line in gmsh, but how can I undo it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GMSH is not a CAD tool that is very similar to other ones. It provides a GUI; however, not all actions can be done through it and even those that can be done, sometimes are much easier done using *some coding*.

GMSH stores all of your actions and data in GEO file format. Say, you added two points and a line between them using GUI. GMSH in the background would have created the following GEO file:

```
//+
Point(1) = {-0.1, 0.6, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(2) = {-0.2, 1.5, 0, 1.0};
//+
Line(1) = {2, 1};
```

where `//+` (comment syntaxis in GEO) separates individual actions.

1. You can open this file (the one that you are currently working with inside GMSH) in your text editor via:
   `Modules -> Geometry -> Edit Script`.
2. Then, delete the last line that creates the line between the two points.
3. Save the file in your text editor.
4. Reload the file in GMSH using `Modules -> Geometry -> Reload Script`

There is also a way to explicitly delete a line: `Modules -> Geometry -> Delete`. Select the line you want to delete and press `e` to complete deletion (follow the hints on top of the window). However, that's not formally an "UNDO". This is a "DO" to do the "UNDO".

While this looks inconvenient from the first glance (and I would agree with you, a devoted menu `UNDO` button would be useful), GEO scripting language offers a lot of flexibility in creating the desired geometry. See the [format description to familiarize yourself with it](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html).

While my advice to shift towards doing more things using the GEO-file rather than the provided GUI is a little beyond the scope of the question, the struggle with the UNDO kind of highlights it.

Comment: Wow ! Awesome answer ! You helped me a lot and saved me a lot of headaches! Great great answer ! :))

Answer (score 2):

Modules -> Geometry -> Remove last script